# Using a Dictionary find a list of all possible words that could be the original string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

My friend had this question in one of his interviews. Although he doesn't remember the question verbatim, he was however able to the recall the bit below to the best of his ability.

A string(one word) is sent from a sender to a receiver.During the transfer process, one letter of the string is changed. Using a Dictionary find a list of all possible words that could be the original string. You don't know what the original string is, you only have access to the string you received and a dictionary.

Upon first seeing this problem the first thing that came to my mind was to iteratively replace all characters of the string from and then compare them to a word in the dictionary. If there was a match then I would store that word in an array.(Assume case insensitivity)

For example:

Original Word: cat

Word received: bat

My Algorithm:

Iterate through the dictionary and put all words of OriginalWord.length() into a HashTable

[a-z]at.....check if any of these is in hashTable

b[a-z]t....check if any of these is in hashTable

ba[a-z]....check if any of these is in hashTable

My friend said that this was the algorithm that he used, but the interviewer said that it was not optimized. I've been doing some research on this question and although I've found none *exactly* like it. I have found some that make reference to Levenshtein distance.  My knowledge of advanced algorithms is limited so I wasn't able to understand it. Also, since I don't have access to the interviewer I'm not able to respond with specifics(e.g. is preprocessing of the dictionary allowed, what happens in so so and so scenarios etc...). Interpret the question as you may and make reasonable assumptions.

Assume preprocessing of the dictionary is allowed. What questions would be good to ask the interviewer in such a scenario and what is a better/more optimized algorithm that can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: `I have found some that make reference to Levenshtein distance. My knowledge of advanced algorithms is limited so I wasn't able to understand it.`  That's not an advanced algorithm, it is a text book example for dynamic programming, which is a standard technique that you are expected to know in job interviews.

Comment: Also, in terms of time complexity, levenshtein distance, or close varaints, will take `O(n^2)` time, same as this approach, assuming the dictionary strings and input string are all of length `n`  (levenshtein distance will have much better constants though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved in linear time if you allow pre-processing of the dictionary by creating an [automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

First create an automaton that decides if a string is in the dictionary, or not. [Aho Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) is one example of algorithm that creates such automaton. A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is also basically doing the same (though less efficiently)

Duplicate this automaton, you now have two automatons, Q1,Q2. The starting state is in Q1, the end state is in Q2. Connect the automatons by adding a non deterministic step from each state in Q1, to its next states in Q2, but with different characters.

For example, if you had states:

```
A---a-->B
```

Add:

```
A--b-->B'. A--c-->B', ...., A--z-->B'
```

Where A,B are the states in Q1, and B' is the state equivalent to B - but in Q2.

This allows you to ignore exactly one mistake, by going to Q2 (and then you can not ignore any more mistakes).

After creation of the automaton is complete (and processed back to deterministic automaton), on query time, you will get the match in linear time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The links that you referenced contain a lot of useful information. You didn't have to be so mean in your other comment though.

Comment: @LekanOsagie Apologies if you got offended that was not my intent. However, for interviews there are some certain things you need to know. It's ok if it's still to early in your proffesional life to know them, and you are not there yet - but you cannot expect to be able to understand advanced interview questions without the proper background.

Comment: An interesting solution. That Q2 automaton is pretty expensive, but quite effective.

Comment: @JimMischel It's expensive if you switch from non-deterministic back to deterministic, otherwise it's "only" doubling space fingerprint. If you keep it as non deterministic, it's the generalization of your answer (implement it with a trie, and you get pretty much the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by creating a trie from the dictionary. But rather than searching it the normal way, you do a wildcard search. Using your example, given the string "bat", you search for "*at". So for every top-level node in the trie, you look for 3-letter words that end in "at".

Then you search for "b*t". That is, you go to top-level node 'b', and for every character that follows 'b', search for 't' as the next letter.

And finally, you search for "ba*". That is, for the prefix "ba", you look for the next character being 't'.

Assuming the letters a-z, this has maximal complexity of 26*n, where n is the number of characters in the word. In reality it'll likely be much less because not all characters will be at all levels. For example, you won't find English words that start with "bz" or "bq".

That'll work, but I seem to remember that you could do it more efficiently with a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).